# how to change layout of the page based on environment value using Jquery in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, config

I have a key with name ENV in config, I have written the following line in layout.cshtml

```
<span class=@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Env"]>@User.Identity.Name
</span>
```

How to write javascript function or suggest some other way to apply different css class file based on ENV value.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a CSS rule in your CSS file that will match the value in your web.config:

```
.someValue {
    color: Red;
}
```

This assumes that in your web.config you have the `Env` key defined:

```
<add key="Env" value="someValue" />
```

Also make sure you put quotes around the class value:

```
<span class="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Env"]">
    @User.Identity.Name
</span>
```

Comment: In this <add key="Env" value="someValue" /> the value can be "DEV" or "Prod" so we wqant one css class to be used for "DEV" and some other class for "Prod" while applying the css class files. Please guide us on this.

Comment: You could define the corresponding rules in your CSS file: `.DEV { color: Red; } .Prod { color: Green; }`. Then based on the value of your web.config the corresponding rule will be used.